# Trying to Send data using jquery .post() to a php file, but data never gets there

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

in my insert.php file I have the following

```
<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">




$(document).ready(function() {
$(".like").click(function() {
var data = $(this).attr('data-id');
$.post("data.php", {'name': data}, function(response){
  $('#dv').html(response);
});
});
 });
```

...

```
<? echo "<br><a href class=like id=buton data-id='$id'> Like (" . $row['likes'] . ")</a>"; ?>
```

...

In data.php I have (just for testing purposes)

```
<script type="text/javascript"          src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(<? echo $_GET['name']; ?>);
</script>
```

...

I am trying to figure out why $_GET['name'] is undefined when I click on the like link. I reaches the data.php file but without the 'name' data. I am a brand new to php and jquery so please do not make assumptions on what I already when answering the question. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you missing the first closing `</script>` ?

Comment: You need quotes around the string you are echoing to javascript in data.php

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing a post and not a get. Why not use $.get() ?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the data via `POST` and checking the `$_GET` php variable which is empty because you are not sending via `GET`.

Change this:

```
alert(<? echo $_GET['name']; ?>);
```

to:

```
alert("<? echo $_POST['name']; ?>");
```

Comment: @Roxon I did close the script right after the first set of code. So I changed the alert box, however now it pops up a blank alert box vs. a pop up box that says undefined.